# Why am I unable to export my xcode instruments data as a CSV? The option is greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-instruments

Currently I'm trying to record the average, high and low framerate of my iOS application by running it through Xcode. I:

1. Load the project in Xcode.
2. go to Product -> Build For -> Profiling and build it to my device (iPad 2)
3. Long-click the play button and select Profile
4. Select the Core Animation instrument when prompted.
5. Press the Record button, launching the app.
6. Perform a 5 minute test. Framerate is displayed in the tool.
7. Press the Stop button to stop the application.
8. Click "Instrument" from the xcode menu to attemp to expore.

At this point the option is greyed out with no explanation. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some instruments do not support exporting to CSV. The Export Track menu item being disabled is a sign the Core Animation instrument cannot export its data to CSV. Disabling user interface elements and menu items is Apple's way of saying you can't do something in Instruments.

If you want to know why the Core Animation instrument cannot export its data to CSV, I have no answer for you. Your best option is to ask on Apple's developer forums. There's a Performance Tools board in the Xcode section. If you're lucky, an Apple engineer may explain why.

You may already know this, but you can save your trace from the File menu. You won't be able to read the data in a text editor, but you can at least examine the trace data in Instruments at a later time.